# trouble getting the location header from a response to a request made through curl

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have logged into a website by posting data with curl. I now want to display the page that a user would normally see after logging in but I can't because the url always changes.

http://some.example.com/niceday/foobar.php?TID=*abcd*
where *abcd* is some seemingly random number.

I've been trying to get the response headers but it keeps giving me the request headers I just sent.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/niceday/dirlogin.php'); //login URL
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postData = 'userName=scott&password=abc123& etc...';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
$store = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);//wrong headers are printed out
```

The headers for the curl_exec($ch) are shown but how do I get the response headers?
I'm not sure if it's relevant but the form where the login credentials are entered uses javascript

Comment: But seriously have you tried to look into google? like get response header curl ? I don't understand it's not laziness because it's more tiring to post a question here than to look into google (i'm not blamming you or whatever it's just I don't understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can get the response header line this : `$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);` But i can't see how it will help you with your problem and then you can use `http_parse_header()` or `explode("\n", $headers);`

update :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mozilla.org/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // HTTP request is 'HEAD'
$headers=curl_exec($ch);
```

This will return only the headers.

Comment: But those are the headers of the request I just made, not the response from the server. For example $headers is missing the Location header which I need.

Comment: still same problem. I edited my question to contain all the relevant code.

Comment: I tried it and it works... the headers are contained in $headers in my code, just try with my code and then adapt with yours

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function my_get_headers($url ) {

       $url_info=parse_url($url);
       if (isset($url_info['scheme']) && $url_info['scheme'] == 'https') {
           $port = 443;
           @$fp=fsockopen('ssl://'.$url_info['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
       } else {
           $port = isset($url_info['port']) ? $url_info['port'] : 80;
           @$fp=fsockopen($url_info['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
       }
       if($fp) {
           stream_set_timeout($fp, 10);
           $head = "HEAD ".@$url_info['path']."?".@$url_info['query'];
           $head .= " HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ".@$url_info['host']."\r\n\r\n";
           fputs($fp, $head);
           while(!feof($fp)) {
               if($header=trim(fgets($fp, 1024))) {
                        $sc_pos = strpos( $header, ':' );
                        if( $sc_pos === false ) {
                           $headers['status'] = $header;
                        } else {
                            $label = substr( $header, 0, $sc_pos );
                            $value = substr( $header, $sc_pos+1 );
                            $headers[strtolower($label)] = trim($value);
                        }
               }
           }
           return $headers;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   print_r( my_get_headers("http://www.mozilla.org"));  

?>
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Array
(
    [status] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [server] => Apache
    [x-backend-server] => pm-web01
    [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [date] => Mon, 15 Aug 2011 14:26:16 GMT
    [keep-alive] => timeout=20, max=999
    [expires] => Mon, 15 Aug 2011 00:36:16 GMT
    [connection] => close
    [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.2.9
    [x-cache-info] => not cacheable; response has already expired
)
```

Function **my_get_headers** was stolen from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#64073

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [`get_gheaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) says: "Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to a HTTP request". Should actually be: "Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to the HTTP request that caused the current script to execute".

Comment: Thanks it works now. get_headers() and curl_getinfo() returned results I was not expecting and that messed it up.